# How to access Word application object

Tags: .net, vba, ms-word, activex, ribbonx

I have VBA which gets called from word ribbon items. VBA calls an activex which i have written using .net as we need it to ran on 64 bit machine. How do I access the host word object from my .net Activex.

Thanks in advance.
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution
Dim app As Word.Application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")